# Обращение к словарю по индексу со списка

Tags: python, list, dict, index

Есть следующий код

```
import random    


number = list('1334')
random_width = random.randint(0, 400)

segment_width = {
        '0': {
            'xmin': 0,
            'xmax': random_width / 4
        },
        '1': {
            'xmin': random_width / 4,
            'xmax': random_width / 2
        },
        '2': {
            'xmin': random_width / 2,
            'xmax': 3 * (random_width / 4)
        },
        '3': {
            'xmin': 3 * (random_width / 4),
            'xmax': random_width
        }
    }
for sym in number:
    print(segment_width[str(number.index(sym))])
```

Он выводит следующее:

```
{'xmin': 0, 'xmax': 45.5}
{'xmin': 45.5, 'xmax': 91.0}
{'xmin': 45.5, 'xmax': 91.0}
{'xmin': 136.5, 'xmax': 182}
```

Почему по индексу 1 и 2 выводит данные первой 3-ки со списка, а не их отдельные значения?
И как это исправить, когда значения списка одинаковые?

Answer (score 0):

> `index()` is an inbuilt function in Python, which searches for a given
> element from the start of the list and returns the lowest index where
> the element appears.

ну вот ваша тройка встречается впервые по индексу 1, поэтому вы ее и получаете 2 раза по индексу 1

или вы хотели число `1234` записать?

т.е. ваш кол делает следующее:

1. разбил строку `1334` в список `['1', '3', '3', '4']`
2. для каждого значения определяется его ближайшее к началу позиция в списке `['1', '3', '3', '4']`
3. индекс переводится в строку
4. из словаря по строке-ключу выбирается значение

для `['1', '3', '3', '4']` получаем индексы соответственно `0, 1, 1, 3`

Comment: Точно. Я не учел это. Как можно по-другому каждому элементу списка присвоить xmin и xmax?

Comment: Если через      for sym in number:
    for i in range(len(number)):
        print(segment_width[str(i)])     то повторные печатает

Comment: а что конкретно вы хотите?

Comment: мне итоге надо сформировать словарь из этих данных в виде {"object": {"class": sym, "xmin": segment_width[str(i)]['xmin'], "xmax": segment_width[str(i)]['xmax']}}

Comment: все равно не очень понял - скажем так - что именно на 1334 должно было быть сформировано по вашей задумке?

Comment: на 1334 должен быть словарь { 'objects': [{"object": {"class": '1', "xmin": 0, "xmax": 45.5}, {"object": {"class": '3', "xmin": 45.5, "xmax": 91.0}, {"object": {"class": '3', "xmin": 91.0, "xmax": 136.5}, {"object": {"class": '1', "xmin": 136.5, "xmax": 182}]}. Нужен цикл, чтобы работал при любом number